# How can I close the Terminal after I quit the last open session?

Tags: terminal

After using several Terminal sessions, I'd like the last `exit` I type to not only close that session but exit Terminal altogether. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can I ask why? macOS just doesn't work like that & never has, for any multi-document-capable app. There's no way to do this natively, you'd need a 3rd party app like [Swift Quit](https://swiftquit.com)

Comment: This is confusing:  the *last* exit you type?  What about the first to second to last?  How would you differentiate between those two conditions?

Comment: You mean you want Terminal to quit when you exit all sessions right? Or is having the window close good enough? I can't remember if it's default behavior but in Preferences→Profiles→Shell you can set the window to close either no matter what or only on clean exits (I think if you type exit then the exit code's 0 no matter what right?).

Comment: @Tetsujin Some applications do work like that, e.g. Preview.

Comment: @Allan It differentiates based on whether there are any other terminal windows still open.

Comment: So, you want `exit` to close windows when there is more than one window open and `exit` to kill the app when only one left? You're going to need a combination of shell and AppleScript to do this.  Why not just `Command-Q` to quit Terminal when you exit the last one?

Comment: @Barmar - Preview behaves like any multi-doc-capable Mac app, as in my first comment. It does not quit when the last window closes.

Comment: I want to achieve precisely what @Allan mentions in their second comment. My motivation, @Tetsujin, is not having to do the `Command + Q` after the last `exit`; certainly not how macOS works, but convenient. What would be the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: @Tetsujin If I open a PDF in preview, then close it (and it's the only one), then go to another application, the Preview icon in the Dock goes away. However, you're right that the application doesn't exit -- I can still see it in Activity Monitor.